# Detect memory leak by overload new operator?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, new-operator

I'm finding the memory leak in my program, I tried the following guide from Microsoft

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
```

But there are some memory leak report items, don't have the source file name and line of code.

I tried to use VLD, but the VLD don't show the file name on call stack, although I did any step in the guides on internet.

From the memory leak report of VLD, I can see the size of block leaked. So I have the idea. Assume that I can overload the operator new, and debug on it, maybe I can detect where memory leak occurred by the special break point as code below.

```
void* operator new (size_t size)
{
    if(size = 1107)
    {
        int temp = 0; //Put the break point here
    }
    void *p = malloc(size);
    return p;
}
```

But I can't overload the operator new, because I an error when compiling the program:

```
Error   166 error LNK2005: "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned __int64,char *,unsigned int)" (??2@YAPEAX_KPEADI@Z) already defined in CommonGlobal.obj    E:\TIN HOC\Learning\Chuong Tring Dao Tao\Working\Main_Code\Mystic\branches\DVRServer\Common\Message.obj Common
```

Someone can tell me how to overload the operator new, for debugging in it?

Comment: Is the overload perhaps defined in a header without `inline`?

Comment: `size = 1107`... those pesky assignments

Comment: @TTGroup, unrelated, but I hope you know that your `if` always evaluate to `true`

Comment: Are you *sure* that's an overload and not an explicitly allowed *redefinition*? And did you put that definition in an implementation-file, where it belongs? (Also, where is the corresponding redefinition of `operator delete` (+ the `delete`-variety passing the allocated size)?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker complains about redefinition of the operator new. You probably defined that function in a header file that is included in multiple files (at least in CommonGlobal.cpp and Message.cpp). Either move it to a source file or add an `inline` specifier to it. If you define the operator new is in source file, make sure it is in only one source file - it applies to all calls to the operator new in all of your source files.

Also the `if(size = 1107)` is suspicious - it will always break and always allocates a memory of size 1107. Change it to `if(size == 1107)` if you want to break when the size is equal to 1107. Under Windows you can also call `__debugbreak()` which breaks into debugger without need to place a breakpoint manually, but you can't expect it to work under different complier than Visual C++.

And for the Visual Leak Detector: did you see a message like `Visual Leak Detector Version 2.4RC2 installed` message in VS's output window and console? If not, switch active configuration from Release to Debug or `#define VLD_FORCE_ENABLE` before inclusion of vld.h.

Comment: Thank you, I add the inline keyword and it built without error. I installed Visual Leak Detector Version 2.4RC2, and the application run as Debug mode. But I can not see the File Name and Line in the VLD logs.

Answer (score 0):

Please include new

```
#include <new>
```

and, how Karoly mentiond,  change the line if(size = 1107) to

```
if(size == 1107)
```

then the program works.

Comment: ---1: Including `<new>` is obviously not going to make a redefinition error go away.

Comment: just as banning "-1" won't make it go away. SO what the hell are you doing, *again*?